# How to get configurable child product by attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a configurable product `"T-Shirt"` with `id = 1`.

I want to get the object for the simple product with size of `"medium"` so I can then query the stock value.

What is the syntax for:

> "Get the medium value of attribute size from configurable parent
>   T-shirt"

Answer (score 2):

Get configurable child product by attribute:-

---

```
$product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($configId);
    #Check if the product has children
    if ($product->type_id == 'configurable') {
        $options = array();
        // Get any super_attribute settings we need
        $productAttributesOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableOptions($product);
        foreach ($productAttributesOptions as $productAttributeOption) {
                    $options[$product->getId()] = array();
                foreach ($productAttributeOption as $optionValues) {
                    $val = $this->trimValue($optionValues['option_title']);
                    $options[$product->getId()][] = array (
                        $optionValues['sku'] =>  $optionValues['attribute_code']."=".$val           
                    ) ;
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks works. although trimValue() errors. Also would be nice to get the frontend option_title (in our case this is size, where we expect to see S, M, Large etc ... instead of a code 51, 31, 22). thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
<?php
    $productId = 1; //config product id
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
    $simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();


    foreach($simpleCollection as $simple){
       //$simple->getName();
        if($simple->getSize() == 'medium'){
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    }
?>
```